# Lubuntu 20,04.1 32/64 bit on a machine?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, 20.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a bit older machine on which I have been successfully running Ubuntu (recently Lubuntu) for a number of years. Lubuntu informs that there is no longer a 32-bit version for Lubuntu 20.4 only 64-bit. Will I be able to use it?

Here's my output from lscpu:

```
Architecture:        i686
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               23
Model name:          Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5500  @ 2.80GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             1356.952
CPU max MHz:         2800,0000
CPU min MHz:         1200,0000
BogoMIPS:            5600.02
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            2048K
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm
```

I have downloaded the image
lubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Will I be able to make use of it!
Hope you will be able to help!

Comment: The CPU supports both 32 and 64bit OSs. So, yes, you'll be able to use Lubuntu 20.04.1 64 bit.

Comment: You have the ability to run 64 bit OSes, as others have already mentioned. But, I'd be more interested in seeing how much RAM you have. Lubuntu 20,04 is heavier than 18.04 and 18.04 is still supported and much lighter. If I had to establish a number, if you have less than 4 GB of RAM, I'd recommend 18.04.

Comment: It depends on your BIOS/firmware. Since it's an older machine, if it's a 32-bit BIOS/firmware, you'll only be able to run a 32-bit OS, even though your CPU indicates that it'll handle 64-bit. Best way to find out is to create a bootable USB flash drive from the .iso that you downloaded, and see if it'll boot.

Comment: I had a look at intel's web site; your CPU is almost 2 years younger than the c2q-q9400 that I have in my box which is running Lubuntu *groovy* (what will be 20.10 when released). I use boxes from 2007 & later to test Lubuntu *amd64*, and older boxes for x86 (32-bit) Lubuntu's (other flavors too).  I'd say 99.9% yep you'll be able to run amd64/x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You can install 64-bit Lubuntu.

The `i686` indicates that now a 32-bit Linux distribution is installed.

You can see that the CPU supports it:

```
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
```

Comment: Tried booting with a USB-stick image of 20.04 LTS. No luck! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you getting some error?

Comment: If you cannot boot the x86_64 / *amd64*, you'll get a clear error such as "*This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU*" which is what I get if I try and boot Lubuntu 20.04 LTS on either a pentium 4, pentium M, intel atom (x86 only) or other x86/32-bit only device  (*I know as I test it each release*). For us to help we need clear error messages & problems.

Comment: Removed all other disks etc except thumb drive from the BIOS boot list, and got message:
"Pen drive without operating system. Remove pen drive and reboot. Operating system not found."
Rebooted with normal disk and got ok boot .
Will next try remaking the USB startup disk with another thumb drive and will report on results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Transferred Lubuntu 20.04 LTS to a different thumb drive: now PC boots OK with offer to install 20.04 LTS. Problem now is with the partitioning. I would like to just replace 18.04 LTS with 20.04 LTS, but this seems to get me into difficulties. Question now is, how can I just get a normal upgrade to 20.04 LTS like earlier? Software updater is set to inform of any new Ubuntu version having long time support, but it just doesn't do this, states that "The software on this computer is up to date". Huh! How do I use command-line apt to force it to give me 20.04 LTS on-line as it should do?